# Power series: if $|x|>R$ then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|a_nx^n| = + \infty $?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

The questions is the following: let the series $\sum a_nx^n$ with a radius of convergence $R$, if $|x|>R$ then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|a_nx^n| = + \infty $?. I can only be sure $|a_nx^n|$ is not bounded, but I can't find a counter example.

Comment: Not really as you can have infinitely many $a_n$ zero say or very small while infinitely many others are large enough to give you the radius $R$ for example geometric series with only even powers or that plus any entire functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\sum z^{2n}$. Here $R=1$ and since $a_n=0$ for $n$ odd it follows that $|a_nx^{n}|$ does not tend to $\infty$ for any $x$.